# Java - Pin lockout in 'programming by doing' tutorial.

Tags: java

I'm stuck on this question http://programmingbydoing.com/a/pin-lockout.html.

```
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int pin = 12345;
    int tries = 0;

    System.out.println("WELCOME TO THE BANK OF MITCHELL.");
    System.out.print("ENTER YOUR PIN: ");
    int entry = keyboard.nextInt();
    tries++;

    while ( entry != pin && tries < 3 )
    {
        System.out.println("\nINCORRECT PIN. TRY AGAIN.");
        System.out.print("ENTER YOUR PIN: ");
        entry = keyboard.nextInt();
        tries++;
    }

    if ( entry == pin )
        System.out.println("\nPIN ACCEPTED. YOU NOW HAVE ACCESS TO YOUR ACCOUNT.");
    else if ( tries >= 3 )
        System.out.println("\nYOU HAVE RUN OUT OF TRIES. ACCOUNT LOCKED.");
}
```

}

I'm told to 'Move the "maximum tries" value into a variable, and use that variable everywhere instead of just the number.' But I just can't figure out how to not use a number and just use a variable. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`3` is a magic number. It just sits there with no description of what it is. You can infer its meaning, but it's not immediately obvious. You can create a variable name for it so it's clearer what it means. It also provides other advantages.

Create a `final` variable called `MAX_TRIES`. This is a constant - the number of max tries never changes. Convention says we should make it all caps. The `final` keyword ensures that its value never changes.

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
int pin = 12345;
int tries = 0;
final int MAX_TRIES = 3; //we refer to this variable instead of the number 3
```

...

```
while ( entry != pin && tries < MAX_TRIES ) //tries < 3
{
    System.out.println("\nINCORRECT PIN. TRY AGAIN.");
    System.out.print("ENTER YOUR PIN: ");
    entry = keyboard.nextInt();
    tries++;
}
```

etc.

Now, if the number of max tries needs to change, you only need to change it in that one place instead of everywhere in the file. it helps readability and consistency.

Comment: It would be better if you provide an explanation about this. Also, in its current state, this solves the problem for this single method but not for all the class.